# Limit or filter edit view in the dashboard to a specific ID only?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have some custom post types. Let's call them `apple`, `banana` and `pear`.

On the frontend I want to add a link for the authorized users to edit the custom post. That is not a problem - that works with `edit_post_link`.

For deletetion I could create `post.php?post=[post_ID]&action=trash`, but it seems that a nonce is needed. Which is good. I don't want the user to accidentally delete the post. When I use a nonce, I think the post gets deleted - straight forward.

That's not what I want, instead I want another link to be added on the frontend of the page which leads to the edit view in the dashboard - let's label it *"manage post"*. Using `edit.php?post_type=[apple|banana|pear]` is quite nice, but I want to generate a link on the frontend to an edit view where only the specific post is listed, i.e. the view is limited to a single ID.

What is the correct syntax to filter the edit view? `edit.php?post_type=apple&post=1337` or `&post_id=1337` similar did not work. How can this be accomplished, if it all?

Edit: I added a picture to clarify what I mean. I want to reduce the view to show only a specific post, e.g. here the first one with `ID=1234`.

[image: Edit View]

Comment: Are you trying to implement this filter because the delete link doesn't work? Just note that you can use `get_delete_post_link( $id )` which will return URL (with nonce) for _trashing_ the post (otherwise `get_delete_post_link( $id, '', true )` will immediately delete it)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: thank you for your comment. That is a good note. It's not the only reason, as I also want to display the post's context, e.g. connected posts, and other columns in that view (even if that's not applicable for the screenshot). So I don't want to focus on the "deletion" use case only, but thanks for the hint!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: BTW, do you know why there is a `edit_post_link` and no `delete_post_link` or `trash_post_link` as well. I mean - where you can simply add a label, text before and after and don't have to care about capabilities on your own?

Comment: Dude, that _is_ `get_delete_post_link`

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: not quite, when you compare it to `edit_post_link` as you can add text before and after and a label text as arguments. But for the link URL itself, you are right. Thanks. ;)

Comment: I see what you mean - tbh it's not that hard to just `$url = get_delete_post_link( $id ); if ( $url ) printf( '<a href="%s">Delete</a>', $url );`

Comment: Note that `get_delete_post_link` still does the capability checking and will return null if the current user can't delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the filter yourself:

```
add_filter( 'request', function ( $vars ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'post', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) )
        $vars['post_in'] = [ $id ];

    return $vars;
});
```

Now if you pass a `post` param in the URL with the ID it will only show *that* post.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have appended your code to my plugin code. The plugin is activated, though when opening `edit.php?post_type=apple&post=1234` or `edit.php?post=1234` the result is not filtered properly. Can you give me a hint how to debug?